# Is there a a container in Java to store objects with many-to-many relations?

Tags: java, algorithm, containers, time-complexity, guava

Is there a a container in Java to store objects with many-to-many relations?

As an example I want to implement a students - subjects database. A student can choose more than one subject and any subject can be studied by unlimited number of students. I want to do search of students by subject with constant or logarithmic time and the same applies to search of subjects by student.

Comment: From Guava, you may want [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Still a nice question; you might want to start reading here https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained too

Comment: You could also use JPA.

Comment: You can also use [new graph API](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) which will be present in [Guava 20](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Graph.html).